# ImageURL got expired after some particular time

Tags: image, base64, wso2-enterprise-integrator, imageurl

I am having set of URLs which needs to converted to base64 in order to push image to Salesforce File object in WSO2 EI 6.3.0. while converting imageUrl to base64 i'm getting **"expires" value too old** message.
here is my code. `

```
                                         <call>
                                            <endpoint>
                                                <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.url}"/>
                                            </endpoint>
                                        </call>
                                        <log level="full" seperator="====Base64Content===="/>
                                        <enrich description="EnrichFileContent">
                                            <source clone="true" type="body"/>
                                            <target property="image_val" type="property"/>
                                        </enrich>
                                        <log level="custom">
                                        <property name="===image_val===" expression="get-property('image_val')"/>
                                        </log>
```

`

I am pretty much sure that there is no issue in my code. because by using that same code , i can retrieved base64 from that same url which previously works. after some time it gets expired.

FYI,

**ImageURL:** https://carsales.pxcrush.net/car/dealer/y67p1dpz5f7zc3swhxi93ur9e.jpg?pxc_expires=20191203040935&pxc_clear=1&pxc_size=2500,2500&pxc_method=limit&pxc_signature=db8a850b8401d95b37fa3658a2fcbb5e

[Getting base64 from ImageURL](http://ruwansrants.blogspot.com/2014/02/mediators-how-to-use-enrich-mediator-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error message is getting printed even if you directly access the URL via browser. Isn't it?

I changed the "pxc_expires" query param to a newer one "pxc_expires=20191226040935". Now I got a different error.

> Bad signature

Then I removed the "pxc_signature=db8a850b8401d95b37fa3658a2fcbb5e" altogether, then I was able to retrieve the image.

Are you sure you are accessing the image from the correct URL? I think, using the correct image URL would solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Arunan,  
    Thanks for your reply. The same url worked fine before some time(approximately 20 days back). i think images was getting expired by using pxc_expires value. So there is no change in ImageURL. please let me know if you have any other solution.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not an issue in EI side.